# What are the folders generated by RocksDB

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

In my kubernetes container I have configured my rocksdb for my kafka streams application

```
containers:
  ...
  volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp/state
              name: state-volume
volumes:
  - name: state-volume
    emptyDir:
    medium: Memory
```

After the deployment if I go to the location `cd /tmp/state/my-service`
I see a dozen of folders. E.g. *0_105, 0_107, 0_9* etc. If I go to one of these folders e.g. `cd /tmp/state/my-service/0_105/rocksdb/state` I see the actual .sst files.
Inside each of these *0_** folders there are multiple sst files which is how rocksdb splits the files keys I suppose. But what do those *0_** folders do and how are they splitted the way they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams create "tasks" based on your program structure and the number of input topic partitions. The directories you sees are task directories that allow each task to store its state locally in an isolated manner.

Each task has a task id `Y_Z` that is used as task directory name. The first number is the sub-topolgoy ID and the second number is basically the input partition number.

You can see what sub-topologies are generated by describing your topology via `Topology#describe()` (you can just call print the `TopologyDescription' to stdout if you want).

Comment: yes I think I found what you are saying here. [Multi-Threaded Compations](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Basics#multi-threaded-compactions)